# How to combine 2 objects into a table by matching their id values?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to combine to two objects together by matching their id values with each other and possibly make it into a table format.

```
$genres = [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "KPOP",
    "music_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-04-19 10:10:10"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "type": "JPOP",
    "music_id": 3,
    "created_at": "2020-02-14 10:10:10"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "type": "OPM",
    "music_id": 2,
    "created_at": "2020-06-30 10:10:10"
  }
 ];
 
 $countries = [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "country": "South Korea",
    "updated_at" : "2020-04-20 10:10:10"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "country": "Japan",
    "updated_at" : "2020-02-15 10:10:10"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "country": "Philippines",
    "updated_at" : "2020-07-01 10:10:10"
  }
 ];
```

The result should be arranged like this (doesn't have to be designed like this, just need to be a simple table):

```
+----+--------+--------------------+
| 1  | KPOP   | South Korea        |
+----+--------+--------------------+
| 2  | OPM    | Philippines        |
+----+--------+--------------------+
| 3  | JPOP   | Japan              |
+----+--------+--------------------+
```

My solution however has been fleshing out the wrong combinations like so (not a table yet because I don't know how):

```
let table = []

 for (let i = 0; i < $genres.length; i++) {
   table.push({
     ...$genres,
     ...$countries.find((countryId) => countryId.id === $genres[i].id )
   });
}

console.log(table)
```

```
[
  {
    '0': {
      id: 1,
      type: 'KPOP',
      music_id: 1,
      created_at: '2020-04-19 10:10:10'
    },
    '1': {
      id: 3,
      type: 'JPOP',
      music_id: 3,
      created_at: '2020-02-14 10:10:10'
    },
    '2': {
      id: 2,
      type: 'OPM',
      music_id: 2,
      created_at: '2020-06-30 10:10:10'
    },
    id: 1,
    country: 'South Korea',
    updated_at: '2020-04-20 10:10:10'
  },
  {
    '0': {
      id: 1,
      type: 'KPOP',
      music_id: 1,
      created_at: '2020-04-19 10:10:10'
    },
    '1': {
      id: 3,
      type: 'JPOP',
      music_id: 3,
      created_at: '2020-02-14 10:10:10'
    },
    '2': {
      id: 2,
      type: 'OPM',
      music_id: 2,
      created_at: '2020-06-30 10:10:10'
    },
    id: 3,
    country: 'Japan',
    updated_at: '2020-02-15 10:10:10'
  },
  {
    '0': {
      id: 1,
      type: 'KPOP',
      music_id: 1,
      created_at: '2020-04-19 10:10:10'
    },
    '1': {
      id: 3,
      type: 'JPOP',
      music_id: 3,
      created_at: '2020-02-14 10:10:10'
    },
    '2': {
      id: 2,
      type: 'OPM',
      music_id: 2,
      created_at: '2020-06-30 10:10:10'
    },
    id: 2,
    country: 'Philippines',
    updated_at: '2020-07-01 10:10:10'
  }
]
```

I would like to know how to make this into a table but I am getting confused so far. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object from the countries keyed on id. Then iterate the genres and you have an O(1) look up on the country object to match country and genre.

```
const countryObj = $countries.reduce((obj, x) => { obj[x.id] = x; return obj; }, {});

for(let g of $genres.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)) { 
    const country = countryObj[g.id]
    if (country !== undefined) {
        console.log([g.id, g.type, country.country].join('|'))
    }
}
```

This assumes all entries in `$countries` have consistent property names for the country name.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const merged=$genres.map(g=>{
  const commonId=$countries.find(c=>c.id===g.id)||{};
  return {...g,...commonId}
})
console.log(merged);
```

With this merged Data. you can create your table!

Comment: Thank you for this! Also may I ask how to arrange the values in this by their ids?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is take each ID from $genres and try to map it with an object of countries. And if they match, I created new object with country attribute from countries and all the other attributes from $genres. So your 2 arrays are merged. Sample code below:

```
let x = [];
$genres = $genres.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.id-b.id;
});

x = $genres.map((obj) => {        
   for(let country of $countries) {
       if(country.id == obj.id){
          return { 'country': country.country, ...obj }
       }
   }
});
```

Now you can use x. If you want to combine two arrays into 1 based on their IDs that can also be done. Replace the return statement to:

```
return { ...country, ...obj };
```

Comment: May I ask how to sort this according to their ids?

Comment: I updated my answer, I sorted genres array first and then did the processing. The sorting is done using array's sort function which takes a function as an input param. I just tried running above code and it worked fine. Try it out and let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes more sense to me now.